# HP UNIX Cobol file format using fhinfo

Tags: unix, cobol

I am trying to get the file definition for some cobol files on our Trizetto Qiclink system that uses HP UNIX.

Supposedly I should be able to use "fhinfo" in the cobol sample programs to get the format definition from the file itself.

Environment variables are all set to:

```
export QIC=/rims
export COBDIR=/rims/cobol
export COBHELP=/rims/cobol/help
export COBPATH=/rims/cobj:/rims/obj:/rims/qwin:/rims/pobj
export PATH=$PATH:/rims/scripts:/rims/iq:/rims/cobol/bin
export SHLIB_PATH=/rims/cobol/lib
```

the cobol compiler is located here "/rims/cobol/bin" it is an executable named "cob"

When I run "fhinfo -i clmhdr" it comes back with the message

```
"**error: cannot find Cobol compiler at: /rims/cobol/**"
```

I have tried changing the COBDIR to /rims/cobol/bin but that does not work either.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
After reading some more on cobol it seems that fhinfo has been replaced with rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

After reading some more on cobol it seems that fhinfo has been replaced with rebuild.